# XML type adapters in bindings.xml file ignored after upgrading cxf-codegen-plugin from 2.7.5 to 4.0.3

Tags: java, jaxb, jakarta-migration, cxf-codegen-plugin

I try to upgrade my project from Java EE to Jakarta EE. To generate Java from WSDL I use **org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin** (before v2.7.5 -> after v4.0.3). Generating goes fine and without errors, unfortunately gets bindings.xml ignored.

Before the two fields (see pictures bellow) were of type **LocalDate** (according to bindings.xml)

[image]

after the update they are of type **XMLGregorianCalender**.

[image]

Binding looks like this:

[image]

What could be wrong? I have no clue. I have got similar result with other plugin as well (**com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-maven-plugin:4.0.2**).

Thank you and best regards
Dalibor

Comment: Add all information as text not as image

Comment: Is the binding file complete here ?